# How to vertically align text with icon font?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I have a very basic HTML which mix plain text and icon fonts.
The problem is that icons are not exactly rendered at the same height than the text:

```html
<div class="ui menu">
  <a href="t" class="item"><i class="large home basic icon"></i><span class="nav-text"> Accueil</span></a>
  <a href="" class="item"><i class="large camera retro icon"></i><span class="nav-text"> Créations</span></a>
  <a class="item"><span class="nav-text">Qui-suis je </span><i class="large help basic icon"></i></a>
</div>
```

[image]

Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: url content not working http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/caFk4/11/

Answer (score 167, accepted):

In this scenario, since you are working with `inline`-level elements, you could add `vertical-align: middle` to the `span` elements for vertical centering:

```
.nav-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could set the `display` of the parent element to `flex` and set `align-items` to `center` for [vertical centering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19461564/2680216):

```
.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: From the question it seems that he wants to align the icons with the text instead of the text with the icons.

Comment: @Arbel I'm not sure - the title says: *"align text with icons"* .. it's essentially the same thing though.

Comment: @Arbel All right I forgot to write if I needed a baseline or center alignment, but both proposal provide a **much more cleaner** result than my initial view so I consider your both answers as good one's.

Answer (score 59):

There are already a few answers here but I found flexbox to be the cleanest and least "hacky" solution:

```
parent-element {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

To support Safari < 8, Firefox < 21 and Internet Explorer < 10 (Use [this polyfill](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility) to support IE8+9) you'll need vendor prefixes:

```
parent-element {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Is the idea to apply this rules to the `a` element? If it is, you are changing the `display` of the link so it's going to convert an inline element into a block one. I don't agree that this is the best solution.

Comment: @Gorzas In that case, I believe you could use `inline-flex` instead of just `flex`

Answer (score 39):

`vertical-align` can take a unit value so you can resort to that when needed:

```
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: 5px;
}

{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To expand on [Marian Udrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2438075/marian-udrea)'s answer:
In my scenario, I was trying to align the text with a material icon. There's something weird about material icons that prevented it from being aligned. None of the answers were working, until I added the `vertical-align` to the icon element, instead of the parent element.

So, if the icon is `24px` in height:

```css
.parent {
    line-height: 24px; // Same as icon height

    i.material-icons {  // Only if you're using material icons
      display: inline-flex;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
}
```

Comment: line-height alone fixed for me.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.menu i.large.icon,
.menu i.large.basic.icon {
    vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/caFk4/13/)

Answer (score 5):

Set `line-height` to the vertical size of the picture, then do `vertical-align:middle` like Josh said.

so if the picture is `20px`, you would have

```
{
line-height:20px;
font-size:14px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand I should apply your CSS code on the `<a>` tags?

Comment: <span> is an inline element , you might want to use a block element like <div>, because <span> reacts weird to sizing css. the key here is to make the text element the same size as your picture, otherwise the center is going to be offset

Comment: sry misread, yes you can do it on the <a> tag too, same thing accross, line-height = element height, this will make everything align perfectly

Answer (score 3):

to center vertically and horizontally use this:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the spans

```
vertical-align:baseline;
```

Didn't work for me but

```
vertical-align:baseline;
vertical-align:-webkit-baseline-middle;
```

did work (tested on Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

**Using CSS Grid**

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <i class="fab fa-5x fa-file"></i>
    <span>text</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/g4r37vbc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property : `vertical-align:middle;`

```
.selector-class { 
    float:left;
    vertical-align:middle; 
}
```