# how to put text and font awesome in a line with a proper way?

Tags: html, css

I just wants to display a font awesome icon and text in a line:

```
<th>
 <span>
  <a>
   <i style="color:green;font-size:22px;" class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
 </span>
 <span> Add Task</span>
</th>
```

It's working but the problem is =>
[image]

If you take a look at above pic then you can see the text is not on the middle of the icon. I tried to put some margin there but it's not working. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you looking for [`vertical-align`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545325/how-to-vertically-align-text-with-icon-font)? ← You can click that

Comment: Never do inline css / js - tis a terrible practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code. Also `display: inline-block` is the droid you're looking for :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Not working!!!

Comment: For accessibility, your text «Add Task» should be inside your link, like in the question linked by domdom.

Comment: as @domdom said vertical-align should solve the problem..

Comment: I think ,vertical-align: middle; will solve your issue. But it is better to include in any of your pre-defined classes.

Comment: beside ....  why so many  tags for 2 pieces of text ?

Comment: @GCyrillus and on that note, why even use *any* tag for an icon? Why is no one using `background-image` anymore?  Or `::before` for that matter. I see this so often. And almost always with class `fa`. Where is that from, I wonder?

Comment: fa is for [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) font icon.

Comment: Ah, cheers @Kustolovic -- now it all makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Target the element containing the font-awesome icon. Set position as relative and adjust top value;

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #333;
}


/*Example 1*/

i {
  color: green;
  vertical-align: sub;
  font-size: 50px;
}

i::before {
  font-size: 30px;
}


/*Example 2*/

span {
  color: green;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

span::before {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!--Example 1-->

<a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Task
</a>

<br>

<!--Example 2-->

<a href="#">
  <span class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Project
</a>
```

Example Code Pen: https://codepen.io/Omi236/pen/KqbQoO?editors=1100

Comment: That's not the right answer, the question was vertical alignement when the icon is bigger. Your icon is at the same size. The solution is just vertical-align.

Comment: I have explained that as well

Comment: Yes but relative position a poor way to solve the problem. vertical-align is more robust, and using a p tag is not useful here, and meaningless

Comment: Is it ok now? I have added both examples.

Comment: better solution :)

Comment: I believe no extra span and vertical-align works fine on its own : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WOLPGY?editors=1100

Comment: @GCyrillus Not always. Sometimes I myself feel the need of aligning them.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you just need to use font size property at parent level.

**Working example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<a style="font-size:16px;"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"style="color:green;"></i><b> Add New</b></a>
</body>
</html>
```